# How are UTF strings literals interpreted in C?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, locale

Say, I want to interpret(i.e. through *stdout*) a UTF32-encoded string: `zß水`, taking the examples found on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbtowc).

With `U` prefix, it's straightforward:

```c
printf("%ls",U"zß水")
```

However, it won't work unless an appropriate "locale" being set before print:

```c
setlocale(LC_ALL, "XXX.UTF-8")
```

**My simplified question** is that, why should we use `XXX.UTF-8` locale settings, instead of some others like `XXX.UTF-32`?

---

My confusion arises when I was testing the code below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <uchar.h>

void test2() {
    char32_t w_str[] = U"zß水";

    printf("wchar width: %d\n", __WCHAR_WIDTH__);
    if(__STDC_UTF_32__) printf("confirmed: utf32 used.\n");

    printf("(with '   C' locale) wide string is interpreted as: ");
    /* set locale */ if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "C") == NULL) perror("setlocale");
    if (printf("[%ls]", w_str) == -1) { perror("            ERROR('C' locale)"); clearerr(stdout); }
    printf("\n");

    printf("(with 'utf8' locale) wide string is interpreted as: ");
    /* set locale */ if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8") == NULL) perror("setlocale");
    if (printf("[%ls]", w_str) == -1) { perror("            ERROR('utf8' locale)"); clearerr(stdout); }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){test2();}
```

Along with output:

```sh
# gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)

wchar width: 32
confirmed: utf32 used.
            ERROR('C' locale): Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
(with '   C' locale) wide string is interpreted as: [
(with 'utf8' locale) wide string is interpreted as: [zß水]
```

According to C11-6.4.4.4-9:

> Prefix  : Corresponding Type
> U : char32_t

and C11-6.10.8.2-1:

> _ _ STDC_UTF_32 _ _ The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that values of type
> char32_t are UTF−32 encoded.

**My complete question** is that, I've already specified an exact UTF32 string literal (and I'm 100% certain that they are exactly UTF32 encoded, by checking the assembly output of the code listed above), isn't it more appropriate to use some locale settings like `XXX.UTF-32`? If not, then why `XXX.UTF-8` is qualified to decode the UTF32 byte sequence?

Comment: Locales must be 8-bit, and with some predefined characters (it is old compatibility rule, for terminals). [for POSIX]. And UTF-32 is not compatible with C strings, so it will require different function anyway. UTF-8 is full compatible with UTF-32, so it will be just extra complication. Note: for localization, you may find newer libraries (and not old locale API).

Comment: `%ls` is not the correct format specifier for `char32_t *`, but there isn't a correct one.

Comment: `printf` outputs narrow characters. `wprintf` outputs wide characters. You would probably need a `c32printf` function to output `char32_t` characters, but there isn't one.